# Is it possible to use bash/shell to open multiple user profiles in chrome

Tags: bash, shell, google-chrome

I was wondering, is it possible to use bash/shell to open multiple user profiles in chrome? I have been trying the following but it opens the one and then nothing else happens.

```
open -a "Google Chrome" --args --profile-directory="Person 1"
open -a "Google Chrome" --args --profile-directory="Person 2"
open -a "Google Chrome" --args --profile-directory="Person 3"
open -a "Google Chrome" --args --profile-directory="Person 4"
```

Comment: Please provide OS and Chrome version

Comment: try adding `&` as the last char to each of those lines. It will run them in the background and allow the next program in your script to be executed. Good luck.

Comment: I am using OSX Mojave and chrome version 76.0.3809.132. 

What would the syntax be for adding the & part to the string ?